# How can I open the same tab when a button is clicked

Tags: javascript

How can I open the same tab when a button is clicked.Meaning this tab is already open "http://www.google.com",when a button is clicked in another page the same URL must override the open one and it must not open the same URL "http://www.google.com" on the already open tab

This is what i tried but it opens the same URL on different new tabs when a button is clicked

```
window.open("http://www.google.com","_blank");
```

Answer (score 1):

Its forbidden to return another tab which is not your one anothers child or parent. You can do it with popups.
in current window any tab is a single window and can have child but cant have relationship with each other due to security issues